# JS HTML Detect/Get Compass Heading for Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, mobile

I'm building google maps based website and  I'm trying to integrate a compass (get mobile absolute heading), but the problem is that I'm getting an absolute heading only for iPhone, while android always gives me relative heading to the direction I loaded the page.

How can I get android heading relative to the north?

Here is my code now:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent && mobile) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
        var dir;
        if (event.webkitCompassHeading) {
            // Apple works only with this, alpha doesn't work
            dir = event.webkitCompassHeading + 180; 
        } else { 
            //tried also event.alpha...
            dir = event.absolute;
        }

        var arrowPath = {
            path: 'M -50 120 L 50 120 L 000 170 z',
            fillColor: black,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            scale: 0.1,
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: 1,
            rotation: dir
        };

        userDirection.setIcon(arrowPath);
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Javascript to get the compass heading for iOS and Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048514/can-i-use-javascript-to-get-the-compass-heading-for-ios-and-android)

Comment: it seems that since 2016 chrome in adnroid doesn't and support absolute orientation ("in respect to Earth's coordinate frame").
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/device-orientation-changes

the alternative doesn't look that promising:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondeviceorientationabsolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, [since 2016](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/device-orientation-changes), Chrome's `DeviceOrientationEvent` doesn't and support absolute orientation:

> Starting with Chrome 50, the degrees included in the
> DeviceOrientationEvent are by default no longer absolute with respect
> to the Earth’s coordinate frame. This means that
> DeviceOrientationEvents should only be triggered when there’s actual
> movement, as detected by some combination of a device’s accelerometer
> and gyroscope. The magnetometer, and false readings due to magnetic
> field fluctuations, are out of the picture.

Strangely, **in practice it does work for iPhone's chrome**, and you can use `event.webkitCompassHeading`  produce absolute orientation, while in Android it is relatively to the initial orientation while loading.

My solution is using `DeviceOrientationAbsolute` ([non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondeviceorientationabsolute), and non-pretty):

```
if (isiOS) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', manageCompass)
} else if (isAndroid) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", manageCompass, true);
}

function manageCompass(event) {
    if (event.webkitCompassHeading) {
        absoluteHeading = event.webkitCompassHeading + 180;
    } else {
        absoluteHeading = 180 - event.alpha;
    }
    console.log(absoluteHeading);
}
```

[Another helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377456/how-to-get-absolute-compass-heading-on-cordova-android-platform) (also works for web browser, not only Cordova).

[Exampled here](https://med-man.co.il) (in mobile)

### UPDATE:

For completeness sake, as of ios13+, iphone demands asking permission only upon user gesture. Full code for ios+android:

on deviceready -

```
TrackOrientation() {

    // starts tracking on deviceready, updates value on currentCompass$ (fallback for ios13+ at "compassPremissioniOS13" funtion)
    if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent['requestPermission'] !== 'function') {
      const deviceOrientationLestener = (event) => {
        if (this.globals.iphone) {
          this.currentCompass$.next(event['webkitCompassHeading']);
        } else {
          if (event.absolute) {
            this.currentCompass$.next(360 - event.alpha);
          } else {
            window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientationLestener);
            window.addEventListener('deviceorientationabsolute', (eventB) => {
              this.currentCompass$.next(360 - eventB['alpha']);
            }, true);
          }
        }
      };
      window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientationLestener);
    } 
  }
```

upon user gesture -

```
  compassPremissioniOS13$() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent['requestPermission'] === 'function') {
          DeviceOrientationEvent['requestPermission']()
            .then(permissionState => {
              if (permissionState === 'granted') {
                window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {
                  this.currentCompass$.next(event['webkitCompassHeading']);
                });
                resolve('User accepted');
              } else {
                reject('User declined');
              }
            })
            .catch(console.error);
        }
      } else {
        alert('deviceorientation is not supported by this browser.');
        this.sendError('deviceorientation = null ("deviceorientation is not supported by this browser.")');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now this option is unavailable in Android. Wait for the next Android update 8.0